# SQL Server Select variable into another variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I build a sql query as:

```
declare @query1 varchar(1000)
declare @results varchar(4000)
set @results = ''

WHILE (condition)
BEGIN
   set @query1 = 'SELECT column FROM table'
   set @results = @results + ", " + (select @query1)
END

print @results
```

So, for example after 2 iterations, I would like to have:

```
columnvalue, columnvalue
```

However, in the above code, @results holds the actual sql query instead.

Answer (score 0):

You never execute query1, but istead assign it the text-string `SELECT COLUMN FROM table`.

What you're looking for is something like `SELECT @query1 = column from table`

Answer (score 0):

declare @query1 varchar(1000)
declare @results varchar(4000)
set @results = ''

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ResultSet') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #ResultSet;
END

CREATE TABLE #ResultSet (mycolumn VARCHAR(1000))

WHILE (condition)
BEGIN
   set @query1 = 'SELECT column FROM table'

INSERT INTO #ResultSet // Temp table to store result of running dynamic query
   exec (@query1)       // Exec to run dynamic query

SELECT @query1 = mycolumn FROM #ResultSet

set @results = @results + ', ' + (select @query1)

END

print @results
drop table #ResultSet

Hope this helps.

Comment: The query 'SELECT column FROM table' is a dynamic sql stored in a local variable. The example provided is kept simple.

Answer (score 0):

OK. this is how it's done:

```
declare @query1 nvarchar(1000)
declare @results nvarchar(4000)
set @results = ''

declare @changesOUT nvarchar(1000)

set @query1 = 'SELECT @changes = column FROM table WHERE condition'

EXEC sp_executesql @query1, N'@changes varchar(4000) OUTPUT', @changes=@changesOUT OUTPUT

set @results = @results + (SELECT @changesOUT) + char(10)

print @results
```